# Check a cell's textLabel before deleting

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView that is being populated with a data source and one that I am also able to delete items from the datasource as well as the tableview itself, all that works fine. What I can't figure out is how to check a tableview cell's textlabel before I delete it. Below is the code that I have right now, as you can see right now I'm checking the indexPath.row before I delete, but this won't work the way I need it to. What I need is a way to read the selected cell's textlabel and compare that to a string in the if statement before I hit the delete button.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        println(playersArray.count)
        println("\(indexPath!.row) index path")


        // check to make sure thye are not trying to delete their own points
        if(indexPath!.row != 0)
        {
            println("DELETE")
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
            playersArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            playersTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

            // save the new data
            // create new array to hold the old persons array converted into NSData
            var personEncodedObjectArray = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(playersArray)

            //push to NSUserDefaults
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(personEncodedObjectArray, forKey: "savedDataKey")
        }
        else
        {
            println("you can not delete your own points")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just not allow them to delete the cell if they can't delete it? i.e. don't even show the delete button on cells they can't delete.

Comment: How would you prevent the delete button from being shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cell for that indexPath and check its properties:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as YourTableCellClass

if cell.textLabel.text == "myText" {
    // whatever
}
```